# Update based on max value of a field in array of objects MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Here's my Customers Collection

```
{
    name: xyz,
    .
    .
    .
    timelines: [
        {
            .
            .
            .
            lastModified: Sat Dec 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
        },
        {
            .
            .
            .
            lastModified: Mon Dec 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
        }
        .
        .
        .
    ]
    createdAt: Sun Nov 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
    lastModified: 'Missing'
}
```

I want to update the main lastModified field with the latest lastModified of the timelines. In this case to Mon Dec 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Answer (score 0):

You need a mechanism which aggregates the documents and gets the maximum date entry from the timelines array, loop through the results list from the aggregation  and update
each document in the collection with this value. A basic approach follows:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$timelines" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "latestDate": { "$max": "$timelines.lastModified" }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc){
    db.customers.updateOne(
        { "_id": doc._id, "lastModified": { "$lt": doc.latestDate } },
        { "$set": { "lastModified": doc.latestDate } }
    )
});
```

---

You can leverage your updates to be more efficient with the bulk API which can update your collection in bulk instead of sending the update request per document, thus making the updates a bit faster and more performant. The following example demonstrates this with the **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** method:

```
var ops = [];

db.customers.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$timelines" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "latestDate": { "$max": "$timelines.lastModified" }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc){
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { 
                "_id": doc._id, 
                "lastModified": { "$lt": doc.latestDate } 
            },
            "update": { 
                "$set": { "lastModified": doc.latestDate } 
            }
        }
    });

    // Send to server in batches of 500 operations only
    if (ops.length % 500 === 0) {
        db.customers.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

// Clear remaining queue
if (ops.length > 0)
    db.customers.bulkWrite(ops);
```